# KeyError: 'user'

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want to extend my Django user model using rest_framework to create an api endpoint for project, but I'm getting a KeyError: user, below is my code.

### profile apiView

```
class ProfileListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    queryset =  Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
```

### profile serializer

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(source = 'pk', read_only = True)
    username = serializers.CharField(source = 'user.username', read_only = True)
    email = serializers.CharField(source = 'user.email', read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'username', 'qualification', 'profession', 'phoneNumber',
                'city', 'address', 'surname', 'firstName', 'dp', 'yearOfExperience',
                'gender'
        )

     def create(self, validated_data, instance=None):
            user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
            user = CustomUser.objects._create_user(**validated_data)
            Profile.objects.create(user=user, **user)
            return user
```

### profile model

```
 class Profile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    yearOfExperience = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    profession = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    dp = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    qualification = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    phoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=GENDER)
    

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('surname', '-firstName', )
        verbose_name = 'Profile'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Profiles'


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


@receiver(post_save, sender=CustomUser)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()
```

Error message:

```
  File "/home/olaneat/Desktop/filez/project/django/funzone/lib/python3.7/site-packages
    user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
KeyError: 'user'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the user is there before accessing it;

```
def create(self, validated_data, instance=None):
    if 'user' in validated_data:
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')

    user = CustomUser.objects._create_user(**validated_data)
    Profile.objects.create(user=user, **user)
    return user
```

However you don't never need to do that `validated_data.pop()` because you're not using `user_data` after assigning it.

Comment: it work but getting a fresh error 
```
 user = CustomUser.objects.create(**validated_data)
  File "/home/olaneat/Desktop/filez/project/django/funzone/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 431, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "/home/olaneat/Desktop/filez/project/django/funzone/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 500, in __init__
    raise TypeError("%s() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" % (cls.__name__, kwarg))
TypeError: CustomUser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'yearOfExperience'

```